# PeerJS error : Cannot receive messages

Tags: peerjs

Hello I'm trying to use PeerJS to send and receive message datas, so take a look to my code:

```
var peer = new Peer({key: 'my-personnal-peer-id-key'});

peer.on('open', function(id) {
  console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id);
});

var dest = prompt("id de destination à appeller")
var conn = peer.connect(dest);
conn.send('Hello!');

conn.on('open', function() {
    console.log('2')
        // Receive messages
    conn.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('3')
        console.log('Received: ' +  data);
    });
});
```

In the window.prompt, I paste the destination peer id, but I don't receive any message in the console log at the following line:

```
console.log('Received: ' +  data);
```

Please help me.

Comment: after connection open(peer and dataconnection) , you will send and receive message

Answer (score 0):

The connection has to have an event listener for 'data' to handle the received data. From your code, it looks like **conn.send()** is called before **conn.on('data')** is executed.

This means when **conn.send** is executed, the connection has no data event listener and hence the sent data is not handled at all.

It could be done like this

```
var conn = peer.connect(dest);

conn.on('open', function() {
    console.log('2')
        // Receive messages
    conn.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('3')
        console.log('Received: ' +  data);
    });
    conn.send('Hello!');
});
```